# Using keyword causes object to go out of scope

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, idisposable

Why does the the object `ok` go out of scope when used in the if statement? and how can I dispose of object `ok`?

```
public class hello : IDisposable { 

}

public class hi{

    private void b() 
    {
        using(hello ok = new hello());

        hello no = new hello();

        if( ok == no )
        {
            ok = no;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: object ok will be disposed after `using` scope  read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx but you need to put `{` brackets to define scope and implement IDisposable

Comment: Encase everything after the using statement in {}. eg - using(var a = new b()){if (a == 1)a = 2;};

Comment: your using block needs to be wrapped in {...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the `using` statement correctly, what you want is as follows:

```
using(hello ok = new hello())
{
    hello no = new hello();

    if( ok == no )//Point 1
    {
        ok = no;//Point 2
    }
}//Point 3
```

Some points (as found in comments above):

1. This will never be true, because you have two difference instances. *Unless*, the class has overridden the equality operator
2. This is not valid and will not compile, you cannot re-assign a variable used in a `using` statement
3. Here `ok` will go out of scope, it will also be disposed at this point, assuming it implements IDisposible - I *think* that it will not compile if it doesn't implement IDisposable anyway

Overall, what you are seemingly trying to do doesn't make much sense at all.